# aspboilerplate call service from startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I need to get the list of tenants in my Startup so that I can validate few items.

I tried adding the following lines in Startup.cs

```
services.AddTransient<TenantAppService>();
var tenantService = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ITenantAppService>();
var tennants = tenantService.GetAll(null);
```

But `tenantService` is always null

**Startup.cs**

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string connectionString = _appConfiguration.GetConnectionString("Default");
        var cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);

        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(PlatformDbContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);
        services
           .AddIdentityServer(options =>
           {
               //options.Discovery.CustomEntries.Add("custom_endpoint", "~/api/custom");
           })
         .AddAbpIdentityServer<User>(options=>
         {
             options.UpdateAbpClaimTypes = true;  // default is true
             options.UpdateJwtSecurityTokenHandlerDefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = true; // default is true
         })
         .AddAbpPersistedGrants<IAbpPersistedGrantDbContext>()
         .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                               options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                                   builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)))          
         .AddSigningCredential(new SigningCredentials(AuthConfigHelper.GetSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256));

        services.AddTransient<TenantAppService>();
        var tenantService = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ITenantAppService>();
        var tennants = tenantService.GetAll(null);

        AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration);

        services.AddSignalR();

        // Configure CORS for angular2 UI
        services.AddCors(
            options => options.AddPolicy(
                _defaultCorsPolicyName,
                builder => builder
                    .WithOrigins(
                        // App:CorsOrigins in appsettings.json can contain more than one address separated by comma.
                        _appConfiguration["App:CorsOrigins"]
                            .Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                            .Select(o => o.RemovePostFix("/"))
                            .ToArray()
                    )
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
            )
        );

        // Swagger - Enable this line and the related lines in Configure method to enable swagger UI
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Platform API", Version = "v1" });
            options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, description) => true);

            // Define the BearerAuth scheme that's in use
            options.AddSecurityDefinition("bearerAuth", new ApiKeyScheme()
            {
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"Authorization: Bearer {token}\"",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = "header",
                Type = "apiKey"
            });

            // Registering File upload operation
            options.OperationFilter<FormFileSwaggerFilter>();
        });

        // MVC
        services.AddMvc(
            options => options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory(_defaultCorsPolicyName))
        );

        // Configure Abp and Dependency Injection
        return services.AddAbp<PlatformWebHostModule>(
            // Configure Log4Net logging
            options => options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
                f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
            )
        );
    }
```

Either I need to pass tenants or `tenantService` instance to  `AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration);` for validation inside `AuthConfigurer.Configure`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I have a similar requirement in one of my projects and I was able to achieve this by placing my `app.MyExtensionMethod()` in the `Configure` method right before `app.UseMvc()`.

Comment: @VitorRigoni Can you please share some code samples? Also my validation happens in AuthConfigurer.Configure(services, _appConfiguration); and not in Startup's Configure

Comment: I didn't post an answer with code samples because I'm not 100% sure on this solution yet. I know it's working, but I still have to test it thoroughly to make sure it's the right call.
Basically, this is my code:
```public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ... other stuff
    app.TestDbConnectivity();
    app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
    app.UseMvc();
    // ... other stuff
}```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IocManager to resolve any dependencies. For instance,

```
var jobManager = Configuration.IocManager.Resolve<IQuartzScheduleJobManager>();
```

For your issue, you can use:

```
var tenantService = Configuration.IocManager.Resolve<ITenantAppService>();
var tennants = tenantService.GetAll(null);
```